# Crash when has IBOutlet connection contentScrollView in Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

In a `Storyboard`, I have an initial `UIViewController` (`FirstViewController`) that Present Modally one `UINavigationController` with a root `UIViewController` (`SecondViewController`).

This `SecondViewController` Show (e.g. Push) another `UIViewController` (`ThirdViewController`) that has a `UIScrollView` with a UIView, that I place my content/components (I called `contentScrollView`).

In this `ThirdViewController`, I put all constraints (top, leading, bottom, trailing) in `ScrollView` to margin 0 with the superView and the `contentScrollView` to margin 0 with the `superView` (that is the `ScrollView`) and to equals Height and Width to the `ScrollView`. In the Height constraint I set low priority to Xcode not show an error in constraints.

When I made an `IBOutlet` with this `contentScrollView` to my `ThirdViewController`.swift, my app crash in run time when I enter in the `ThirdViewController`.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, if is the constraints, or another configuration.

The app crash with this log: "[`UIView refreshControl`]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ..."

When I Present Modally this `ThirdViewController`, this bug don't occur.

I made an example project to simulate this bug: https://gitlab.com/lucas_foton/bugscrollview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to connect `IBOutlet` for `contentScrollView` so just remove it and your project won't crash.

**EDIT:**

Looks like problem is with `contentScrollView` name you gave to `IBOutlet` if I changed it to `contentView` and it's working fine.

Comment: In my project I use the IBOutlet to change some properties of the view, such as the background color that I had defined in a library of color.

Comment: I made a work around to fix my problem, I set clear background color in contentScrollView and set the custom color in scrollView (the IBOutlet in scrollView doesn't crash). But yet I would like to understand why this crash is happening.

Comment: And I am not sure about the exact problem here because it may be Xcode bug or something is predefined for `scrollView` which is blocking this `IBOutlet` to work.

Comment: Happy to help.. :)